# How do I solve the inequality $2(x-3)^2 < 32$?

Tags: inequality, quadratics

> How do I solve this inequality?
> $$2(x-3)^2 < 32$$

Currently, I solve such inequalities by sketching. This just seems weird and I think there is much more to it than I know. What insights have you gained from thinking about such inequalities?

Comment: All inequalities (meaning: equations with $<$ or $>$ instead of $=$) are solved the same way: First you replace the inequality sign with $=$ and solve that. Once you have got those roots, you draw a sign table and determine in what regions (between the roots) the equation is true. That's that.

Comment: This is two questions in one. The existing answers only answer one of those questions.

Comment: @MattiP. Only if all of the expressions involved are continuous functions of the variable you are solving for.

Answer (score 3):

Try this
$$
2(x-3)^2 < 32
\\
(x-3)^2 < 16
\\
|x-3| < 4
\\
-4 < x-3 < 4
\\
-1 < x < 7.
$$

*The important lesson is:* When you have $(x-3)^2 < 16$ and you "take square root of both sides", you do not get $x-3 < 4$.

Answer (score 2):

We notice that $2$ is a factor common to both the LHS and RHS. So we essentially reduced the problem to finding the solutions to the inequality:
$$(x-3)^2 < 16$$
Noting that $16 = 4^2$, we bring it to the LHS. We then get,
$$(x-3)^2 - 4^2 < 0$$
Applying the algebraic identity $a^2-b^2 = (a-b)(a+b)$
$$\implies (x-3-4)(x-3+4) < 0$$
$$\implies (x-7)(x+1) < 0$$
Since the product of these $2$ factors is negative, we must conclude that *one of them must be negative while the other is positive*. So, two cases are possible:

**Case 1:**    $x-7 > 0 \implies x>7$ **and** $x+1<0 \implies x < -1$  (Not possible)

**Case 2:**    $x-7 < 0 \implies x<7$ **and** $x+1>0 \implies x > -1$

Hence, via case 2, we conclude that the solution to the inequality is $x \in \ (-1,7) $